# webpack-concat-text-plugin "node" is incompatible

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, yarnpkg, webpack-plugin

The `concat-text-webpack-plugin` is nested deep in some package, and errors when I have NextJS and Node 18.

```
error concat-text-webpack-plugin@0.2.1: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">=8 <=16". Got "18.16.0"
error Found incompatible module.
```

It's fine with Node 16. Looking into the package code there is a line

```
"engines": {
    "node": ">=8 <=16"
},
```

which blocks using Node 18+. The repo is archived and cannot be PR'd.

How can I use this with Node 18+?

Answer (score 2):

For me, this error came from the fact that:

1. concat-text-webpack-plugin was required by [serverless-bundle](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-bundle)
2. I was running an outdated version of serverless-bundle

Serverless bundle [resolved this in the 6.0 release](https://github.com/AnomalyInnovations/serverless-bundle/releases/tag/v6.0.0), so to solve this in my codebase, I ran `yarn upgrade serverless-bundle@6` which removed the bad dependency and allowed me to upgrade to node 18.

Since serverless-bundle is very popular, it's likely this solution will work for most people. If your codebase includes concat-text-webpack-plugin through some other package, you can find the culprit by running `yarn why concat-text-webpack-plugin` which will show the top-level package causing this dependency. You can then most likely upgrade the top level package.

Answer (score 1):

This lead me down a rabbit hole and I have come out a much better developer. I forked the repo, and rewrote the tests to work with Node 18+ and Webpack 5. The tests relied on some knarly behaviour of webpack which was completely removed from v4 => v5.

I published a package here https://www.npmjs.com/package/concat-text-webpack-plugin-2023

The key bit is that the original package is regularly a nested dependency. This new version has the same API as the original and has included README on how to make the resolutions work with nested deps.